# Node equivalence class identification

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms

Let $(V, E)$ be a directed, unweighted, unlabeled graph. Define a *grouping* as a partition $P$ of $V$ into disjoint subsets $g_i \subset V$ such that for all groups $g_i \in P$ and any two vertices $v_0, v_1 \in g_i$, for any group $g_j \in P$,
$$\Big\lvert\left\{ e \in E\ \middle\vert\ e = (v_0, w) \text{ for } w \in g_j \right\}\Big\rvert = \Big\lvert\left\{ e \in E\ \middle\vert\ e = (v_1, w) \text{ for } w \in g_j \right\}\Big\rvert,$$
and similarly
$$\Big\lvert\left\{ e \in E\ \middle\vert\ e = (v_0, w) \text{ for } w \in g_j \right\}\Big\rvert = \Big\vert\left\{ e \in E\ \middle\vert\ e = (v_1, w) \text{ for } w \in g_j \right\}\Big\rvert.$$

- Choose a grouping $P$. Let $f$ be a mapping from $(V, E)$ to itself such that for all $v$ in a group $g \in P$, $f(v)$ is also in $g$. Then $f$ is a graph automorphism of $(V, E)$. Does this work in the other direction to allow the construction of groupings from collections of automorphisms?

I can confirm that groupings always exist; at the very least, there is a trivial grouping $P_{trivial} = \left\{\{v\}\ \middle\vert\ v \in V\right\}$ with each element in its own group. I also know that in a number of cases, there are better groupings (i.e. partitions with less than $|V|$ groups). Define an *optimal grouping* to be a grouping $P$ such that no grouping $P'$ has less groups than $P$.

- Are optimal groupings unique? I suspect so, but I don't have firm evidence one way or another and would not be surprised if there's some annoyingly nice graph with more than one optimal grouping.
- How could one efficiently find an optimal grouping (faster than brute-force testing all possible partitions of $V$, at least)?
  Note that every grouping is a subpartition of the partition of $V$ arising from the degree equivalence relation $\sim$ in which $v_0 \sim v_1$ if and only if $v_0$ and $v_1$ have the same in- and out-degrees. That might help establish a starting point for an algorithm, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Please let me know if the question of an algorithm for optimal groupings is better suited to another SE community.

### EDIT: As Misha Lavrov pointed out in the comments (thanks!), this question, as currently formulated, is predicated on the untrue claim about automorphisms which constitutes the first bullet point.

An updated version can be found here (will be a link once I write the updated question).

Comment: The fact about automorphisms is false. Consider an $8$-cycle; this has a grouping that alternates $g_1, g_2, g_1, g_2, g_1, g_2, g_1, g_2$ around the cycle. Not every permutation of the vertices that preserves this grouping is an automorphism; for example, I could swap a single pair of opposite vertices, while leaving the rest in place.

Comment: @MishaLavrov my apologies; I generally work with unlabeled graphs and forgot to specify so. Does my edit resolve your problem? Thanks for bringing that to my attention!

Comment: I don't see how the graph being labeled or not is relevant. An $8$-cycle has a grouping into two parts $g_1$ and $g_2$, both of size $4$; there are some ways to permute the vertices that respect the grouping but are not automorphisms.

Comment: But they are automorphisms of an unlabeled graph, in that the resulting graph will look the same up to renaming the vertices that were permuted.

Comment: There is no "resulting graph" in this case; the function that swaps two opposite vertices while leaving the rest in place is not an isomorphism because it does not preserve adjacency of vertices.

Comment: I believe we are talking about slightly different types of objects. I will repost the question with diagrams to illustrate the specific type of graph-like object I am considering such that the automorphism fact is true. Thank you for pointing out the inconsistencies in my current formulation.